# How can I do nginx rewrite..?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want to use nginx rewrite..

If cliend request is 
`http://localhost/v2/{anyalphabet}/subdir`
then I want to show
`/docs/index.html` ... this is physical location.

I tried like this

```
location /v2/ {
    rewrite /v2/*$ /docs/index.html;
}
```

Is it impossible?

Comment: It's absolutely possible, but I can't understand what you mean by `physical location`. Is it a path on disk? Also, `rewrite` works with regexps, not shell substitution chars, so it should look like `rewrite ^/v2/.+/subdir /docs/index.html;`